# How do I clean burnt milk from a glass-ceramic stove?

Tags: cleaning, stove

I have a glass-ceramic stove (Ceran), and I did spill some milk on it,  which of course instantly burnt itself onto the surface. It seems resistant to any mild way of removing it, and I'm not sure how harsh I can try to remove it without damaging the glass-ceramic surface.

What is the easiest way to remove such burnt milk from a glass-ceramic stove without damaging it?

Comment: Soak with full strength Ammonia in a sponge or paper towel for about half an hour. Then try a Scotch scouring pad, their green may be soft enough to not scratch. Full strength ammonia is hard on the lungs, try to not breath it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try.  I'll list them from most conservative to

- Let it cool. Squeeze some cleaning paste on it, and cover with a
  paper towel. Wet the towel, let it soak, then buff it with the paper
  towel or a non-scratch scouring pad.
- Magic Eraser-type melamine foam sponge
- Plastic razor blade scraper, sometimes called "Safe    Scraper" sold
  at hardware and automotive stores
- Metal razor blade scraper

Answer (score 2):

I tried the cerama bryte and wasn't budging. Then I put down baking soda with enough water to make a paste and it came right up very easily with paper towel. I am not sure I have ever gotten my stove top that clean. I will use only baking soda from now on. I was amazed!!

Comment: Thanks for advice with the baking soda paste to clean spilled milk off glass top stove. It works wonders. Also didn't take long to wipe off. Have to use a little extra elbow grease. But, it's gone.

Comment: I used the baking soda+water paste too and scrubbed it off just after applying with the rougher side of those blue sponges and it came off great; thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

After looking at these fine answers and going to Safeway during the COVID19 debacle I couldn't find Baking Soda. What I did see was Mr Clean Magic Eraser...worked great and quickly. Its a white sponge that you wet, squeeze on the spot and then wipe off with a little elbow grease.